# Need Tutorial of UAmodalPanel

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, ipad, uiviewcontroller

I have seen a very nice sample code for [UAmodalPanel](http://code.coneybeare.net/uamodalpanel-an-open-source-modal-panel-alter) as the link below. But after i downloaded the code, I have no idea how it works. Does anyone have any idea and know if there is any tutorial for that?

Many Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UAModalPanel is quite simple to understand.  If you don't want to use blocks or delegates, simply create an instance of the panel and call -showFromPoint: like so:

```
//create panel instance
UAExampleModalPanel *modalPanel = [[[UAExampleModalPanel alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.bounds title:@"Example"] autorelease];

// Add the panel to our view
[self.view addSubview:modalPanel];

// Show the panel from the center of the screen
[modalPanel showFromPoint:self.view.center];
```